# Block port every twenty minutes for a couple of seconds

Tags: networking, port, router

I want to be able to block a certain number our home network's ports every 10-20 (arbitrary number) of minutes for a couple (again not really important) of seconds.

Reason is my son playing computer games too much and he agreed to only play twice a week but instead plays almost every day. I understand its not "nice" to drop out of the game because then one is called a "dropper" or something by one's peers. (He often told me they would call him that if i just pull the plug). So by the method described above I intend to use this peer pressure style of force to make him honor our agreements. If i block the ports in the above manner he will always be able to start a game but then get kicked out of it after a few minutes and I hope he will therefore not try to play during the off-days and only during the days we agreed on. 
I know i could just block them for lets say mo-thu and sa all day long but then it would be more of a forced control on my part. through the other method it's more of a peer thing which i hope he's more likely to adhere to. I don't want to forbid him to play I just want him to not want to play during that time(because then he ll continue to be called a dropper in those days)

Comment: This sounds like an attempted technical solution to a management problem.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't tell us what router you are using.  I will give you the commands to set it up in Linux, using `iptables` and the `recent` module.

You will have to change `$port_to_block`, `$play_seconds` and `$stop_seconds` accordingly.

```
iptables -N PLAY_CHECK
iptables -N PLAY_START
iptables -N PLAY_STOP
iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --dport $port_to_block -j PLAY_CHECK

iptables -A PLAY_CHECK -m recent --name NOT_PLAYING --rcheck --seconds $stop_seconds -j DROP
iptables -A PLAY_CHECK -m recent --name PLAYING ! --rcheck -j PLAY_START
iptables -A PLAY_CHECK -m recent --name PLAYING --rcheck --seconds $play_seconds -j ACCEPT
iptables -A PLAY_CHECK -j PLAY_STOP

iptables -A PLAY_START -m recent --name NOT_PLAYING --remove
iptables -A PLAY_START -m recent --name PLAYING --set
iptables -A PLAY_START -j RETURN

iptables -A PLAY_STOP -m recent --name PLAYING --remove
iptables -A PLAY_STOP -m recent --name NOT_PLAYING --set
iptables -A PLAY_STOP -j DROP
```